# 1U Dell or other NVME m.2 / u.2 Capable RAID server Advice Needed

Tags: raid

I am looking to build a new webserver and am in need of some hardware advice. Currently I have a Dell Poweredge 1950 with Dual Xeon E5345, Win 2008, 16GB RAM,  very solid server, zero problems. It is now several years old and time to upgrade not only the Hardware but to the latest OS. I don't want to upgrade unless I can get a server with hardware RAID 5 for the latest Samsung 960 NVMe m.2 / u.2 512GB Drives x 4.

Here are my requirements, not set in stone except #2:

1. 1U Dell or other quality comparable server 2 U if needed but prefer 1U
2. Capable of utilizing 4 m.2 / u.2 NVME drives with Hardware RAID controller
3. 64GB RAM
4. Dual Intel Xeon processors... Might not be needed but I guess would prefer
5. Redundant Power Supplies
6. Dual LAN cards
7. Installing Windows Server 2016

Thanks